# Angular Date Pipe en-GB incorrect 24 hour time format

Tags: angular, internationalization

When using the Angular DatePipe with locale `en-GB` it is returning times in format "short" or "medium" in 24 hour format, for example 13:00 instead of 1:00 pm. Is anyone aware of a way to provide the formats for the locales to override the default (incorrect) 24 hour time format?

Comment: You can write your own date pipe

Comment: ISO 8601 has been adopted as British Standard, so it is the correct format.

Comment: @RobinDijkhof interesting that those in the UK don't seem to agree ;) in that case it does sound like I need to build a workaround for this as suggested